# How to skip "Catalog URL Rewrites" from index:reindex:all in Magerun

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magerun to run Indexing for my magento store. I am using below command

```
/usr/local/bin/magerun --root-dir=/var/www/html/store index:reindex:all
```

The above command works perfectly but my requirement is to skip the "`Catalog URL Rewrites`" using index:reindex:all command.

Is this possible to skip single Index in reindex:all command?

Is there any command/parameter provided by magerun to skip any Index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to skip specific indexing

```
/usr/local/bin/magerun --root-dir=/var/www/html/store index:reindex catalog_product_attribute,catalog_url,catalog_product_flat,catalog_category_flat,catalog_category_product,catalogsearch_fulltext,cataloginventory_stock
```

we can pass parameters after index:reindex seprated by comma.